# Ruby: Folder structure for sub-class workers

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand the folder structure I need to create to meet the below gem requirements:

I'm using this gem `sidekiq-sequence` and as part of it you need to create a `Sequence` class.. Like so:

```
class TestSequence < Sidekiq::Sequence::Base
  step First
  step Second
end
```

And then those workers `First` and `Second` need to be a subclass of the `TestSequence` class.. Like so:

```
class TestSequence::First
  include Sidekiq::Sequence::Worker

  def perform
    # Perform your job
  end
end
```

My question is, is how to create the file structure for this? Do I need to create a file AND a folder in my workers directory named `TestSequence` ?

Would it be:

- app/workers/test_sequence.rb
- app/workers/test_sequence/first.rb

Comment: I can't say for sure as I don't have a Sidekiq instance to check this on but having looked at the README it suggests that each worker is just like any other worker and none of their examples are namespaced in a module. I would suggest putting each class directly into `app/workers` as a file without nesting, so that all your sequence classes and worker classes live side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, I needed to create a file and a folder with the same name. The folder structure I needed was this:

- app/workers/test_sequence.rb
- app/workers/test_sequence/first.rb

In order for this to work:

```
class TestSequence < Sidekiq::Sequence::Base
  step First
  step Second
end
```

And this:

```
class TestSequence::First
  include Sidekiq::Sequence::Worker

  def perform
    # Perform your job
  end
end
```